# Method undefined in main, working with a deque

Tags: java, queue, deque

I am working with a deque

```
MyDeque theQueue = new MyDeque(queElm);
```

in main `MyDequeApp` that calls a method

```
theQueue = insertFront(10);
```

the method is in a class called `MyDeque`

```
public void insertFront(Item x)
{
    if(front==maxSize)
        front=0;
    queArray[front++]=x;
    nItems++;
}
```

I am getting an error in main when calling `insertFront` saying

> The method insertFront() is undefined for type MyDequeApp

I don't understand this error as I believe the method is defined in `MyDeque`, if someone could shed some light it would help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `int` value, but it requires `Item` object.

```
 public void insertFront(Item x)
```

If you look at method signature, this method with name `insertFront` accepts values of type `Item`

Comment: so this only takes values from the Item class, how can i go about inserting an item here in the app?

Comment: @Dan: It depends on how your class, instantiate Item class and set value to it (assuming it has that option).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method incorrectly. `insertFront` is a method on the `MyDeque` class. So to call it you need to call it from your instance of `MyDeque`. The error is saying you're calling it from `MyDequeApp`, not `MyDeque`.

Replace:

```
theQueue = insertFront(10);
```

With:

```
theQueue.insertFront(10);
```

As Nambari mentioned, you're also passing the wrong kind of value. It's expecting an `Item` but you're passing an `int`. Instead, create an instance of `Item` and pass that to the method.

I'd personally also change the name of the variable since it's a deque, not a queue.